# How to start class function - that sets kivy label text - from within __init__

Tags: python, kivy

So I'm trying something like this:

**test.py**

```
class Test():
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.label_value = "LABEL"
        self.set_label()

    def set_label(self):
        self.ids["label_kv"].text = self.label_value
```

**test.kv**

```
<Test>:
    Label:
        id: label_kv
```

**Error Message:**

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

How can I do this?

Full issue:
I am working with several Screens with ScreenManager, and I want to paint a bar chart from values gathered by user input. When user input is done, I want to change screen and paint this bar chart, but as of now I can only do this by adding an extra button on the new screen that "starts the painting bar chart" - process. This must be a very basic problem, nevertheless I find it quite frustrating since this extra initialize-paint-bars-button screws up my design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an intermediate property - conceptually, your `Test` has an api exposing the things you want to set, the kv language defines a widget structure that may make use of that api, and the python code may set things in that api to have them propagate to the kv.

For instance:

```
class Test():

    label_text = StringProperty()
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.label_text = "LABEL"
```

and

```
<Test>:
    Label:
        text: root.label_text
```